# Grouping polygon neighbors recursively using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, adjacency

I have a shapefile with polygons and need to group them with the same Group_ID if they touch each others. The thing is, once I start assigning a number to one polygon, it needs to keep looking for neighbors of neighbors until all are assigned the same ID in the attributes table. For example:

[image]

The grouping should be like:

```
Polygon_ID          Group_ID
1                      1
2                      1
3                      1
4                      1
5                      1
6                      1
7                      1
8                      2
9                      2
10                     3
```

I am using QGIS for this, trying a script with python with a recursive function that keeps checking for neighbors until no more are found, no luck so far.

Comment: If you're amenable to ArcGIS, I have an arcpy function to do this.

Comment: post your code --

Comment: if you know postgis you can use the st_clusterdbscan function for this fairly easily

Comment: In ArcGIS I would try dissolve-(multipart to singlepart)-calculate an id column, spatial join this back to the original polygons. This must also be possible i QGIS

Comment: @Tom Sure, this has to be done once a year so I can group in Arc and get the shape back to QGIS if needed, thank you.

Comment: @ziggy Thanks for the info, with this I can even group polygons that dont strictly touch but are close enough to be considered a group.

Comment: @BERA Thanks, never thought of this but should do the trick aswell.